# How to group by multiple params of an object of a list in java 8 and remove duplicated rows?

Tags: java, java-8

This my code :

```
public class User{
        private String id;
        private String userName;
        private Long birthDate;
        private String address;
        private boolean enabled;
        //Constructors
        // Getters && Setters
        ...
}

public class ServiceUser{
    List<User> users=new ArrayList<>();

    public ServiceUser(){
        users.add(new User("OPS","MESSI",15454222454L,"ADRESSE 1",true))
        users.add(new User("TA1","RICHARD",1245485456787L,"ADRESSE 1",true));
        users.add(new User("XA5","LANG",659854575424L,"ADRESSE 2",true));
        users.add(new User("DS7","RICHARD",1245485456787L,"ADRESSE 1",false));
        users.add(new User("OPD6","LONG",659854575424L,"ADRESSE 2",false));
        ...
    }

    protected List<User> getFiltredUsers(){
        // TODO here
    }
}
```

I would like to get a list of users like :

```
User("OPS","MESSI",15454222454L,"ADRESSE 1",true)
```

How to remove all duplicated rows whitch have the same userName, birthDate, address ?

> Nb: the user list is returned by the database, and just for the
>   example i put it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code deletes duplicates and returns only distinct elements from your list of users:

```
//used for grouping them by name, birthday and address
static Function<User, List<Object>> groupingComponent = user ->
Arrays.<Object>asList(user.getName(), user.getBirthday(),user.getAddress());
//grouping method used for grouping them by groupingComponent and frequency of it
private static Map<Object, Long> grouping(final List<User> users) {
    return users.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(groupingComponent, Collectors.counting()));
}
//filtering method used for filtering lists if element is contained more than 1 within a list
private static List<Object> filtering(final Map<Object, Long> map) {
    return map.keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(key -> map.get(key) < 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Simple usage would be: `filtering(grouping(users));`

```
System.out.println(filtering(grouping(users)));
```

---

**UPDATE 3:**
To be honest it's a bit tricky because of those three parameters( birthday, name and address ). The easiest way I could think of right now would be to implement hashCode and equals methods in your User class like( to mark users same if they have those three values same ):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (43 + 777);
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // checks to see whether the passed object is null, or if it’s typed as a 
    // different class. If it’s a different class then the objects are not equal.
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    // compares the objects’ fields.
    User user = (User) obj;
    return getName().contains(user.getName())
            && getBirthday() == user.getBirthday()
            && getAddress()== user.getAddress();
}
```

and following method to delete all duplicates

```
   public static List<User> filter(List<User> users) {
        Set<User> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<User> uniqueUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<User> doubleUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Boolean, List<User>> partitions = users.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(user -> set.add(user) == true));
        uniqueUsers.addAll(partitions.get(true));
        doubleUsers.addAll(partitions.get(false));
        uniqueUsers.removeAll(doubleUsers);
        return uniqueUsers;
    }
```

Comment: Thanx @MS90 but this method remove only one of the tow dupliacted rows not both ?

Comment: This method **returns only distinct Users** denoted by three params **username, birthdate and address.** Can you try it and test it? @TinyOS

Comment: Well i want that if it found a duplicated rows it remove them , you see !

Comment: Completely? You don't one to be left? You want both of them deleted? @TinyOS

Comment: i want both of them deleted

Comment: Take a look at answer now. Happy coding. @TinyOS

Comment: last question plz !  filtering method return a list of object and not list of User ! that what i am looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `List`:

```
List<User> users=new ArrayList<>();
```

You could use a `Set` (I used a `HashSet`, in this example):

```
Set<User> users=new HashSet<>();
```

`Sets` do not allow duplicates, so that way you don't even need to filter.

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: In facte the the user list is returned by the database, and just for the example i put it like that.

Comment: You could always convert it to a `Set`:  `Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<>(users);`